# Solving $333.443,35 = 30.000\frac{1,02^n - 1}{1,02^n \cdot 0,02}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms

I can't reproduce the intermediate steps when it comes to solving $n$ in:

$$333.443,35 = 30.000\frac{1,02^n - 1}{1,02^n \cdot 0,02}$$

It says

$$n = - \frac{\log (1-\frac{333.443,35}{30.000}) \cdot 0.02}{\log(1,02)}$$
$$= 12,7$$

Looks like $333.443,35$ was divided by $30.000$ first. Then somehow $\log$ was applied and nominator became denominator.

Can someone show me step-by-step what happened?

Comment: Put $x:=2^n$ for the moment. Then solve $a=b\frac{x-1}{x}$ for $x$. Finally $n \ln(2)=\ln(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is of the form $M=s \frac{r^n-1}{r^n(r-1)}$, where everything except $n$ is known.

$$\frac Ms = \frac{r^n-1}{r^n(r-1)} \Rightarrow (r-1) \frac Ms=1-\frac {1}{r^n} \\
\Rightarrow r^{-n}=1-(r-1) \frac Ms$$

Now take logs on both sides and divide by $\ln r$  It looks to me like $0.02$ should be inside the parentheses.

Comment: It felt a bit complicated, but I got it now thanks to you. The end was $1,02^{-n} = \frac{3889}{5000}$ and then applying log like $-\frac{\ln(\frac{3889}{5000})}{\ln(1.02)}$

Is there an easier way to solve this?

Comment: @RamanujanTaylor Not that I can think of, but this one seemed pretty straightforward to me.  Just isolate $n$ and go from there.